# How to predict advantage value in deep reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, prediction

I'm currently working on a collection of reinforcement algorithms: https://github.com/lhk/rl_gym

For deep q-learning, you need to calculate the q-values that should be predicted by your network. There are many strategies: monte-carlo, temporal-difference, TD(lambda), ...
Basically you get a tradeoff, between the number of steps you look into the future, and the variance of your observations.

Instead of predicting the q values, it is also possible to predict advantages. Where `A(s, a) = Q(s, a) - V(s)`. So the advantage describes how much more than expected you get. It is discussed and motivated [here](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching_files/pg.pdf).

For predicting the q values, you have to balance variance against the number of steps to look into the future. For the advantages, there is a method called generalized advantage estimation (GAE) which does this in a very neat way:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438

I would like to predict those advantages, instead of q values. That is by no means a new idea, and apparently, advantage learning can outperform q-learning: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/learn-43/lib/photoz/.g/web/glossary/advantage.html

The above link is a very small abstract on advantage learning. The important part is:

> Advantage learning [...] requires only that the A(x,u) advantages be stored

But how do I do that ?
The GAE paper assumes that I can predict the value for every state. I need the values to calculate the advantages.
As far as I can see, I have to options:

- Predict only advantages and then somehow calculate the value from the advantage. As far as I can see, we need two out of: q-values, advantages, values. So if I don't want to predict the values, I have to predict the q-values. Which is the original problem. I read somewhere that the maximum advantage is the value, but that makes no sense to me and I can no longer find the link.
- Predict both advantage and value. If I do this, implementing GAE and training the network to predict the advantages correctly would be simple. But what would I use as training target for the value ? If I use the GAE formulation for the advantages, it looks many steps into the future. It seems nonsensical to base the calculation of those advantages on a value function approximation that I train on one step lookaheads.

My question is not how to set up a function approximator, or what network types would be well suited for this. My question is: What are the target values for the value function, that I can feed to my function approximator.
How do I actually train it ?

Comment: Re: "I read somewhere that the maximum advantage is the value". The maximum advantage in an optimised system (where Q and V calculate values for the optimal policy) is zero.

Comment: @NeilSlater, oh that makes sense. Perfect counterargument for this idea that max(advantage) = value.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the Advantage function $A(s,a)$ is estimated from *only* the value function $V(s)$, since:
$$\begin{align}
A(s,a) &= Q(s,a) - V(s) \\
       &= r(s,a) + V(s') - V(s)
\end{align}$$
Basically, to do so you need only to learn $V(s)$ because $Q(s,a) = r(s,a)+ V(s')$ can be written in terms of the immediate reward plus the (discounted) value of the next state $s'$. This is done by minimizing the squared error (MSE) between $V(s_t)$ and the (discounted) returns $G_t=r_0+\gamma r_1+\gamma^2 r_2+\cdots$ such that:
$$\phi \leftarrow \alpha \nabla_\phi \big(V_\phi(s_t) - G_t\big)^2,$$
where $\phi$ are the parameters of the value network $V_\phi$. Once you lean $V_\phi$ you can estimate $A(s,a)$ as in the first equation or, better, with the [GAE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438) approach (able to balance bias and variance by setting $\gamma$ and $\lambda$).

Alternatively, if you learn a Q-function $Q_\theta(s,a)$ and your actions are discrete, you can estimate the advantage as follows:
$$A(s,a)\approx Q_\theta(s,a) - \frac1{|\mathcal A|}\sum_{a'\in\mathcal A}Q(s,a')$$
because $V(s) = \frac1{|\mathcal A|}\sum_{a'\in\mathcal A}Q(s,a') = \mathbb{E}_{a\in\mathcal A}\big[Q_\theta(s,a)\big]$.

> the maximum advantage is the value

As correctly stated by @NeilSlater this is not true. Assuming optimal value functions $V^\star$ and $Q^\star$, the advantage of the optimal action $a^\star$ is *zero* because:
$$\begin{align}
A^\star(s,a^\star) &= Q^\star(s,a^\star) - V^\star(s) \\
             &= Q^\star(s,a^\star) - \max_{a\in\mathcal A}Q^\star(s,a) \\
             &= Q^\star(s,a^\star) - Q^\star(s,a^\star) \\
             &= 0
\end{align}$$